# how to fix this error : [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:

Tags: python, path, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a python script that create a GUI application that display a list of existing files after the user select a path.

The system display in the **QlistWidget** fileName and its parentFolder.

I want to get the full path of the selected file from the list

**example :** C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx

The system display this error :

> [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:
>   'C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx'

How to fix this error.

**Note :  I am using self.fullpath variable as a global variable.**

```
        print("chdir ==> {}".format(os.chdir(PureWindowsPath(self.fullPath))))
```

the code above is what makes the error. where I am trying to change the current directory path to the selected path of the file.

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
            try:


                if self.listWidgetPDFlist.viewport() == obj and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
                    #*********


                    it = self.listWidgetPDFlist.itemAt(event.pos())
                    print("it ==>{}".format(it.text()))
                    ##*********
                    Item=str(it.text())
                    print("item ==> {}".format(Item))
                    print("full path ==>{}".format(PureWindowsPath(self.fullPath)))


                    print("chdir ==> {}".format(os.chdir(PureWindowsPath(self.fullPath))))
                    parentFile =Path().resolve().parent

                    print("parent file ==>{}".format(parentFile))

                    selectedFile = os.path.join(str(parentFile,Item))
                    print("selectedFile ==>{}".format(selectedFile))

                    if self.hoverItem != it:
                        message = selectedFile

                        QtWidgets.QToolTip.showText(QtGui.QCursor.pos(), 
                            message, 
                            self.listWidgetPDFlist.viewport(), 
                            self.listWidgetPDFlist.visualItemRect(it))
                        self.hoverItem = selectedFile

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you pass to `os.chdir()` function is invalid because it’s not a directory it’s a file path. You need to exclude file name from it and then pass it to `os.chdir()`:

```
os.chdir(PureWindowsPath(os.path.dirname(self.fullPath)))
```

Comment: i tried your answer and i got as printed result :

`it ==>Desktop\test_arabic.docx
item ==> Desktop\test_arabic.docx
full path ==>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx
chdir ==> None
parent file ==>C:\Users\test
decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, WindowsPath found`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to debug the Python test cases in Visual Studio Code, when I hit Debug Test for the test definition/method I got [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: error

I solved it by updating the "cwd" parameter in launch configuration from

```
{
        "name": "Unit Testing",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "test",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    },
```

To

```
{
        "name": "Unit Testing",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "test",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/"
    },
```